# Cross reference 2 different columns, then put count of values in another table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet, and I want to be able to go through one column (O) to find the different values, then go to another column (U) and count whether the sting is paper or electronic. Then, I want to be able to take the total of paper/electronic stings from U with each instance in O (source) and put it into the following table on a different sheet with VBA.

Due to the sensitivity of the data, I quickly made a table with basically what I mean. Pretend A is O and B is U.

[image]

And I want the output in this table, or if there is a better way to present the data:

[image]

I've tried making a pivot table, but it simply counts each instance of the paper/electronic string in the sheet, and I need to cross reference the values in O with U.

Comment: Can you show some data as an example in your table?  (You speak of column O and U, but you're showing a table without column letters)

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit long and I had to hard code, but I found a solution, thanks to @AnmolKumar I looked in to Countif and found this:

```
ws2.Range("F15").Value2 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs, _
(ws3.Range("O1:O" & lstRow2), "A", ws3.Range("U1:U" & lstRow2), "Paper")
```

I'll just have to do it for each different section

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula what you desire. Remember that we need to change source value and Fillining medium value in each row. you can see from the image that in formula for Source A values are "A" and "Paper" for paper count and "A" and "Electronic" for electronic count. the formulas for Source A are written at the bottom of the table and formula for Source C you can See from formula Bar. This is to show you the change you need to make in formula for each source.

[image: Formula]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Thanks for you kind suggestions. I thought showing formulas with input and output would be helpful. But Moreover added general syntax for testing. But i would keep that in mind in future.

Answer (score 1):

if you have excel 365 you can just use the unique/countifs function. For simplicity I assume your data is in col A & B

To get the unique values (source) col E:

```
=UNIQUE(A:A)
```

To count (manually add "paper" as header in col F:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;E2;B:B;$F$1)
```

Do the same for the other values.

EDIT:

Anything can be done in code:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub DictUniqueFinal()
        Dim arr, arr2, arrH, j As Long, dict As Object, id As String
        'setup some arrays
            arrH = Split("Source, Paper, Electronic", ",")
            arr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Value2 'load source without headers
            ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 3)
        
        'setup the dict
            Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create dictionary lateB
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1 'traverse source
                id = arr(j, 1)
                If Not dict.Exists(id) Then 'create key
                    If arr(j, 2) = "paper" Then
                        dict.Add id, 1 & "," & 0
                    Else
                        dict.Add id, 0 & "," & 1
                    End If
                Else 'update key
                    If arr(j, 2) = "paper" Then
                        dict(id) = Split(dict(id), ",")(0) + 1 & "," & Split(dict(id), ",")(1)
                    Else
                        dict(id) = Split(dict(id), ",")(0) & "," & Split(dict(id), ",")(1) + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        
        'build final array
            ReDim arr2(0 To dict.Count - 1, 1 To 3)
            For j = 0 To dict.Count - 1
                    arr2(j, 1) = dict.Keys()(j)
                    arr2(j, 2) = Split(dict.Items()(j), ",")(0)
                    arr2(j, 3) = Split(dict.Items()(j), ",")(1)
            Next j
            
        'dump to sheet
            With Sheet2
                .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, UBound(arrH) + 1)).Value2 = arrH
                .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(arr2) + 2, UBound(arr2, 2))).Value2 = arr2
            End With
    End Sub
```